# Proving a sequence goes to zero from bounded sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose for nonnegative sequences $\{a_k,b_k,c_k\}$, we have
$$
0 \leq \sum_k a_{k} (b_k - c_k) < C
$$
for $C<\infty$. Let $\sum_k a_k =\infty$ hold and $b_k \to 0$. Will this imply $c_k \to 0?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n= b_n =\frac{1}{n}$ and define
$$c_n = \frac{1}{2} \quad\text{if} \quad \exists k, n=k^2 \quad \quad \quad \text{ and } \quad \quad c_n = 0 \text{ otherwise}$$

Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^N a_k(b_k-c_k) = \sum_{k=1}^N a_k b_k-\sum_{k=1}^N a_kc_k = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor} \frac{1}{2k^2} \longrightarrow \frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

And $\sum a_k = \infty$, $(b_k)$ tends to $0$, but $(c_k)$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Choose b<sub>k</sub>=0 for all k, a<sub>k</sub>=1 if k is even and 0 if k ist odd, c<sub>k</sub>=0 for even k and 1 for odd k. Then they're certainly all nonnegative and the sum in the question is bounded by C=1 since every term of it is 0 (either a<sub>k</sub>=0 or b<sub>k</sub>-c<sub>k</sub>=0). The sum over a<sub>k</sub> diverges and b<sub>k</sub> →0 but c<sub>k</sub> doesn't converge since it "jumps" between 0 and 1.